# how can I find the total number of lines in a file and also detect the empty lines by using CGI and Perl

Tags: cgi

I have a script which reads a text file and print it. How can I detect the empty lines in the file and ignore them.
is there any way to find out the total line number of the file without running the

```
while (<$file>)
$linenumbers++;
```

Answer (score 0):

To print the number of non empty lines in a file

```
perl -le 'print scalar(grep{/./}<>)'
```